# Best practice for creating Neo4j relationships fast in a large loading process?

Tags: neo4j, etl

I'm writing an ETL process that creates a graph from scratch each time with about 350k nodes and 800k relationships. The creation of the nodes using LOAD CSV is very fast. But the creation of relationships seems slow (takes hours) whatever method I use, and slows down considerable when properties are being written to the relationships. There are composite indexes on the nodes, and no indexes declared for relationships.

What's the best practice for creating relationships?

Comment: please show us how you create relationships so that we can answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXPLAIN on your relationship-creation statement to see if the indexes are actually used.

I presume you batch your rel-creation? Otherwise it might eat up too much memory for the tx to complete (quickly).

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "url" AS row
call { with row
MATCH (s:Node {id1:row.source1, id2:row.source2})
MATCH (t:Node {id1:row.target1, id2:row.target2})
CREATE (s)-[r:REL]->(t) SET r.prop1 = row.prop1
} in transactions of 50000 rows;
```

Also check your memory config for heap and page-cache.